# Await for a process to finish execution

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a process that takes some varying time to execute. The proceeding part of the code depends on its results.
The process creates a printable file (PRN) file. The proceeding section then reads that file and returns its bytes contents.

When i put a breakpoint at the using statement, i get to read the bytes of the created file and return them to where they are being requested. But when i execute as usual, i get the error.

**_ The process cannot access the file 'linkToFile' because it is being used by another process _**

```
lbl.PrintSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
byte[] fileBytes = null;

Task.Run(() => { lbl.Print(int.Parse(qty)); }).Wait(2000); 

using (var strm = File.Open(outPutPrintFile, 
                              FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         strm.CopyTo(ms);
         fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}

return Ok(fileBytes);
```

I tried to put the part that executes longer in a Task-Wait part but still getting the same error.

Comment: How do you execute that other process from your C# program? If done the right way (and assuming you are not just piping commands to cmd.exe), your code should likely be able to wait for that process to finish before attempting to access the file...

Comment: @elgonzo The fact is that lbl.Print is coming from another API that am consuming. It generates a PRN file for me and then using traditional C# methods, i push it forward to a destination printer.

Comment: The API may be poorly written. In particular, it'll need to make sure to actually close the file handle it opens if it did not open it shareable, otherwise you'll get exactly this sharing violation -- the "other process" may just be your own. You can try `GC.Collect()` to see if GC will dispose it for you and make the file available again, but if that works, fixing the code is obviously a better idea still.

Comment: 2 suggestions: (1) Check the documentation of tha other API If there is a way to get notified about or to wait for the print job being finished. If this is not possible (2) Don't use async/tasks but move the code in a background thread. You might also perhaps play dirty and employ a loop. Within the loop, try to open the file and if this succeeds simply exit the loop. If opening the file fails, let the loop sleep for a certain amount of time (maybe 1s) and the let the loop iterate again, doing the same routine again. (Move this loop into a background thread so it is not blocking the UI thread)

Comment: For some unknown reason,  the Fileshare.ReadWrite produced the desired results. Would like to mark you @Rahul as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Fileshare.ReadWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netframework-4.8#fields) instead of `FileShare.Read`. It's not for some unknown reason as you commented but `ReadWrite` make sure that further Read/Write operations can be done on opening the file. From your posted code it looks to be the option to choose.